# Jest Teardown in config file for multiple tests suites

Tags: javascript, express, jestjs, knex.js, supertest

I'm making an API for a website (this is open source you can find the repo and look by yourself here : https://github.com/PirateSeal/Operation-Green-Axe-2)

I'm making tests suites with jest and supertest and i'm using knex to connect and talk with my db.

My problem is that i can't run multiple tests suites because the first one is "locking" access to my db.

In each of my tests files I implemented the BeforeAll() and AfterAll() methods to create and teardown my db and instead of doing that for each test, i'd like to create a setup file that will run before all tests suites and after all.

I read about jest setup file but i didn't understand how to use it.

Can you help me please ?

(this is my first question here btw pls be kind :) )

Comment: Good way to start could be that just create a single database for testing and run jest tests sequentially instead of parallel. After that you can start thinking how to make completely parallel running possible. Last time I created few databases that can be used for testing and pooling for them. Then before each test database connection details were requested from that pool so that each database was allowed to be used by only one tests case or file at a time.

Comment: if i understood your answer, i think that's what i aimed to do first : i want to execute each test file one after the other on the same test database. But right now i can't because i'm using the BeforeAll() and AfterAll() methods to create a database but for each tests files and that's not what i want : i want to create my test database before running all tests files and tear it down when they all are executed. I want to use a setup file from jest, but i don't understand the doc on how to make it possible.

Thanks for your answer btw

Comment: I've been doing it in a way that I just drop old testdb and run DB initialization / migrations for test database again, before even starting test run. After all tests has been ran I just leave created DB there  (for example for examining what happened in some failed test).